# Alternative to Android BluetoothServerSocket in Windows Phone 8

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to know if something like BluetoothServerSocket exist in Windows Phone 8. I have a device that search for a specified service name and connects to it , in android this is achieved by

```
       BluetoothServerSocket btSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("MY_SERVER_NAME", MY_UUID_SECURE)
       .....
       .....
       BluetoothSocket socket = btSocket .accept();
```

I need to do the same in Windows Phone 8, but all I managed to find is

```
       PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:PAIRED"] = "";
       var devices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
       PeerInformation peerInfo = devices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.DisplayName.Contains("MY_DEVICE_NAME"));
       StreamSocket s = new StreamSocket();
       await s.ConnectAsync(peerInfo.HostName, "1");
```

The problem with this approach is that the device need to be paired with the phone for the phone to communicate with the device. Where in Android pairing is not required.

If anyone know how to make a windows phone go into a Bluetooth listening mode please help me out, thanks.

Comment: start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx and http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Introduction_to_Bluetooth_support_on_Windows_Phone_8